# Latin (or Greek) -x becomes -ght?

Tags: etymology, loanwords, latin

I have attested two words in English that come from two Latin words. These are "night" and "light". They derive from the words "nox" and "lux" respectively; both Latin — in the case of the word "nox", though, this one might also derive from Greek "nyx".

Nevertheless, the question is: is this a normal transition and happens often, or has it happened because of the word wasn't a direct loanword from Latin, but it came through other languages?

If so, do we have any other word in English that ends with *-ght* and its Latin counterpart ends with *-x*?

Comment: As others have pointed out, the English forms you mention are not derived from Latin. But it's not that English doesn't have forms derived from those Latin(ate) forms; just look at words like *nocturnal* and *luminous*.

Comment: @jyc23 - "luminosus" and "nocturnalis" are both latin words...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These English words did not come from Latin.  Rather, Latin and English both inherited these words from Proto-Indo-European (though not directly — there were intermediate languages).  The nouns *light* and *lux* came from PIE **leuk-*, while the adjective *light* came from PIE **le(n)gwh-*.  *Night* and *nox* came from PIE **nok(w)t-*.

So, *x* did not become *ght*.  Instead both of these words came from a language that existed about 5000 years ago; during those 5000 years, the pronunciations of the words changed many times.

It may be relevant to note that both *night* and *light* were pronounced with a /[x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative)t/ in Proto-Germanic (the language that came before Old English). It is only later on that the "gh" became silent.

(Etymology data came from [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com).)

Answer (score 2):

A correspondence between English '-ght' and Latin '-ex' is a bit fluid, given the vagaries of English spelling and historical phonetic and semantic drift in both Germanic and Italic and the different ways they divergesd from common Proto-Indo-European roots.

But to limit ourselves, the only three English/Latin pairs like this are **night** / **nox**, **light** / **lux**, and

**right** / **rex**.

(and this seems to have separated semantically more than the other two ('rex' = 'king' or ruler, from the past participle 'rectum' of 'rego' to rule.)

For other possible English-Latin pairs:

- 'eight' corresponds to 'octo' (no 'x')
- 'aught', 'naught', 'ought', 'fight', seem to be solely Germanic (see  Etymonline for online references)

For Latin-English pairs:

- 'sex' corresponds to 'six' (no '-ght' in the Engilsh)
- 'lex'  corresponds to 'law' (which are cognate
- 'crux' corresponds to 'cross'
- 'vox' corresponds to 'voice'

Whenever these are pairs, I've only given actual cognates, but the phonetic or spelling rules diverged from the ght/x pattern.

Comment: The base form of lex (law) is "lex, legis (leg-)" which is the root of the English word legal.

Comment: @Adam: yes, the PIE versions of all of these have a velar followed by a dental. In English (in Germanic) and in French (in Romance) the velar experienced lenition (lenited?). 'legal' is simply a modern professional/academic creation/borrowing directly from Latin.