# Five Thousand year old word, ght

Tags: meaning

There was an [answer here June 2011 by Kosmonout](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/29551/191178) stating,

> So, *x* did not become *ght*. Instead, both of these words came from a language that existed about 5000 years ago; during those 5000 years, the pronunciations of the words changed many times.

I want to know what this 5,000-year-old language was, the culture, and in what area of the world the language was spoken, and what was the meaning of the word ght?  Thank you!
This is my first time to use this site, so if i'm not clear on how it is does please explain.  Thank you.

Comment: Also, in that post, *x* and *ght* are not words, just parts of words.  The questioner asked whether *x* in certain Latin words like *lux* had "changed" to *ght* in corresponding English words like *light*.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer says,

> These English words did not come from Latin. Rather, Latin and English both inherited these words from **Proto-Indo-European.**

According to a 2015 [article in *Science* magazine](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2015/02/mysterious-indo-european-homeland-may-have-been-steppes-ukraine-and-russia),

> Two long-awaited studies, one described online this week in a preprint and another scheduled for publication later this month, have now used different methods to support one leading hypothesis: that PIE [Proto-Indo-European] was first spoken by pastoral herders who lived in the vast steppe lands north of the Black Sea beginning about 6000 years ago.